# Manage sheet range length on Google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am having a "Cannot read property 'length'" error on this code that I do not understand.
For me `newRangeVals[0].length` should get the length of the sheet.

The code is created, for each file of a folder, to get data from an URL and to only keep data contained in the title

Does someone has an advice on this ?

```
  var name = spreadsheet.getName();
  let range = sheet.getDataRange(),
      maxRows = sheet.getMaxRows(),
      srchCol_1 = 2,
      srchPatt_1 = new RegExp(name)
      newRangeVals = range.getValues().filter(r => r[0] && srchPatt_1.exec(r[srchCol_1])),   
      numRows = newRangeVals.length;  
  range.clearContent();
  sheet.getRange(2,1, numRows, newRangeVals[0].length).setValues(newRangeVals);
  sheet.deleteRows(numRows + 1, maxRows - numRows);
```

Answer (score 1):

@Antoine, just after `range.clearContent();` add

```
console.log(numRows + " | " + newRangeVals[0].length)
```

I preseume that there is no data corresponding the the name of sheet. If true, add a test beforewards

Comment: Thank you but this did not change anything

Comment: of course, but what is the result in the console ? th aim is just to see where the issue comes from!

Answer (score 0):

`newRangeVals` will only be populated if there's a row in which:

- Value in column C matches the spreadsheet name (`srchPatt_1.exec(r[srchCol_1])`).
- Column A is populated (`r[0]`).

If you are getting this error, that means `newRangeVals` is empty, which most likely means there's no row where both these conditions are matched. Double-check the sheet data so that the conditions are matched for some rows.